# After successful installation of new version of python, only the old version shows up in terminal

Tags: python, macos, installation

I am trying to install python 3.12 but even after a successful installation terminal shows me the older version of python.

I installed it 2 ways: using the python installer from the website and homebrew.
Each time it shows that it successfully installed.

I ran it like this:

```
brew install python@3.12
```

I also tried this (chatGPT suggested it):

```
pyenv install 3.12.0
pyenv global 3.12.0
```

However none of this seems to install python 3.12 correctly.

When I run this:

```
python --version
```

It shows this:

```
Python 3.11.5
```

I would like the newest version of python. Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: try 'which python3' and 'which python' and see if the path is the version being returned from python --version, something like, '/usr/local/bin/python3 --version'

Comment: can you run `python --list` command to see the list of installed python versions. I don't know if this command is the same for mac but I use windows.

Comment: Doesn't it tell you after running `brew install python@3.12` that you have to use `python3.12`, `pip3.12`, etc. or run a certain command to make it your default? Something like `brew link --overwrite python@3.12`

Comment: `python` used to refer to `python2` on macOS until they removed it. Now it's undefined by default. So if it's aliased to something like `python3.11` then you have to also change that alias in your bashrc/zshrc or similar config file where it is defined.

Comment: _Either_ use pyenv or brew (or macports, or nix). They're different approaches, and you can _either_ have a `python` from pyenv _or_ a `python` from brew be first in your PATH; but if one of them is providing your default interpreter, that means the other one isn't.

Answer (score 0):

After extensive troubleshooting this is what solved the problem:

```
unset PYTHONHOME
```

Not sure why - but after running this, terminal now shows the newest version of python.

Answer (score 0):

The alias python3 in brew have not been changed to version 3.12. Here is the pull request for your reference:

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/150390

You can create a symbolic links manually.

```
ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/python3.12 /opt/homebrew/bin/python3
ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/pip3.12 /opt/homebrew/bin/pip3
```